# Downgrade .Net Core project from 3.1 to 2.2 - The type or namespace name 'IWebHostEnvironment' could not be found

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.2

I had to downgrade a .Net Core 3.1 project that was scaffolded using:

`dotnet new angular -o my-new-app`

This should now be for .Net Core 2.2, Angular v8.

I am now getting:

> error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'IWebHostEnvironment' could
>   not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly
>   reference?)

This is on the line:

`public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)`

The auto-suggest fix options in Visual Studio 2019 are not helpful, as they are all "Generate Interface", nothing about a potential missing package.

My using declarations on this class are as follows:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.AngularCli;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;`
```

These are all valid (unflagged) references.

There are a slew of other errors also.  What am I missing here?

[image: Errors after Downgrade]

**Edit**

The only reason I am even going this route is because I am unable to deploy to Azure using .Net Core 3.1, even though my App Service is set to use that version (LTS).

> The current .NET SDK does not support targeting .NET Core 3.1.  Either
>   target .NET Core 2.2 or lower, or use a version of the .NET SDK that
>   supports .NET Core 3.1.

This is the error on the Azure server on the CI process.  The only information I've seen is that Microsoft is not fully ready for .Net Core 3.1 Azure CI, but I find that somewhat hard to believe.  For simplicity's sake I just want to downgrade to 2.2, which I know works fine with Azure, and meets the needs of my project.

I deleted the App Service on Azure and re-created it as a .Net Core 2.2 App Service, hosted under Windows.  These other issues I am having is on the attempt to downgrade to 2.2 on my own machine.

**Edit 2**

Here are my current dependencies, all are showing 2.2 including the SDK.

[image: Project Dependencies]

Comment: `IWebHostEnvironment` is only available in .NET Core 3.0 and 3.1. You won't be able to use the code as-is in 2.2. It looks like it was the replacement for `IHostingEnvironment` according to the [migration docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio)

Comment: @Herohtar What I'd like to do is re-scaffold this under a new project just to see how it scaffolds out `Startup.cs`, however if I run `dotnet new angular -o my-new-app` it still scaffolds this out as a 3.1 .Net Core application.  I can't seem to find out how to force this to be a 2.2 scaffold, unless I have to download the project templates.

Comment: You would probably have to have that version of the .NET Core SDK installed and run that specific version of `dotnet`, if that's even possible. You could probably just look up the 2.2 project template if that's all you're wanting to see.

Comment: @Herohtar I found a workable example here: https://github.com/dileno/Blog-tutorial-Angular-8-.NET-Core-2.2-CRUD/blob/master/Startup.cs ... however when I try this route I get "error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'HttpsPolicy' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.AspNetCore' (are you missing an assembly reference?)" on `using Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy;`

Comment: @Herohtar I actually uninstalled the .Net Core 3.1 SDK and re-installed 2.2 (although that was already on my machine).  I don't have any 3.x related SDKs currently installed.  The scaffolding command-line tool appears to use whatever the latest version of .Net Core is and I don't see any way to force it to scaffold to a lower version of the framework.

Comment: We have a .net core 3.1 app on azure and it was a bit of a pig to get the Azure CI (bitbucket) working, but it can be done with a custom deploy script. I'll rummage it out later - Azure does support net core 3.1 but a few things are quite set up to make it as seamless as "connect to repo, wait, done" of earlier versions. But if a nuisance really because the stuff that does work is EOL and there isn't really an upgrade path at the mo. Think they dropped the ball a bit with the timescales of the various LTS versions and what was being EOLed

Comment: @CaiusJard Thanks, I don't have time to fiddle around with custom deploy scripts for this particular pet project.  I am backing down to 2.2, it suits my needs.

Comment: Might be advisable to look at a doc aimed at users upgrading from 2.2 to 3 - Microsoft cleaned up a lot of ambiguity in namespaces but largely left functionality alone. Upgrade is more likely than downgrade so you might find more resources concerned with explaining upgrade changes and be able to apply them in a downgrade fashion

Comment: @CaiusJard But why am I seeing "The current .NET SDK does not support targeting .NET Core 3.1. Either target .NET Core 2.2 or lower, or use a version of the .NET SDK that supports .NET Core 3.1." on Azure?  The App Service was created on Windows .Net Core 3.1 but it is telling me the SDK doesn't exist?

Comment: I don't really understand the last sentence of your comment. The error message is emitted by the device compiling the code. That device lacks the relevant sdk. When you connect an Azure app service to a repo, the azure machine will download the repo and compile it then put it live. Azure cannot compile 3.1 right now. I think even though a suitable sdk is on the Azure machine, it doesn't use it, but I'd have to check what we did with our build script to be sure

Comment: Checked on this and most machines on Azure don't have the 3.1 SDK on- it seems a few of our Linux boxes in smaller regions did have it, possibly as a phased rollout plan but it hasn't been rolled out across the Azure estate yet. We currently build our 3.1 app locally using Jenkins then deploy it with octopus but if you want to make your life simpler you could probably publish it from VS and just nominate someone to be in charge of deployuntil the CI is sorted out

Comment: Here are a couple of resources that may be useful - one a map showing which regions have what SDK and runtimes: https://aspnetcoreon.azurewebsites.net/#.NET%20Core%20SDK and the other the discussion on the problems encountered rolling out 3.1: https://github.com/Azure/app-service-announcements-discussions/issues/129

Answer (score 4):

you can use IHostingEnvironment instead of that in .net core 2.
of course you have to make sure you have installed .net core 2.2. sdk.

Comment: This does not resolve the issues, when I change this I get "CS0104 'IHostingEnvironment' is an ambiguous reference between 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.IHostingEnvironment' and 'Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.IHostingEnvironment'".  Is this due to some sort of package that should no longer being brought in?

Comment: IHostingEnvironment has name space Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting in .net core 2.2 but this namespace has been changed to Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting in .net core 3 and upper. you need to remove this name space in using section to remove ambiguity

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this resolved by installing the following project template:

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=BernardoLloret-Fuentes.aspnetcore22withangular7

This allowed me to create a new project from scratch, which I could copy the `Startup.cs` and `Program.cs` files from, as well as duplicate the installed NuGet packages.

This resolved all of the errors that resulted from switching the project from Core 3.1 to Core 2.2.

There were other code changes involved due to using some of the 3.1 features such as `Range` but I backed those down to 2.2 compatible code changes, and all is working again.

If anyone else is attempting this, here are the NuGet packages you will need to move this down from 3.1 to 2.2:

[image: 2.2 NuGet Packages]

Comment: Worth noting that 2.2 is end of life. And it's 2.1 that is on long term support. Users following these steps should expect to upgrade soon to something like 3.1 LTS when Azure sort it out

Comment: @CaiusJard Understood, but all I need is something that works, and 2.2 works fine for my Angular 8 application.  There is no need for 3.1 and until Microsoft themselves can sort out why the proper SDKs are not installed for CI via GitHub, then I need to get work done.

Comment: The feedback I had was that Azure held off deploying 3.1 for security concerns but I haven't checked the authenticity of this myself

Comment: A note on this, they do not want you to specify a version on Microsoft.AspNetCore.App, Azure will warn you on build.  Edit the project file to remove the `version=""` attribute on that assembly.